# executing query from ruby on rails the right way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just beginning with ruby on rails and have a question regarding a bit more complex query. So far I've done simple queries while looking at rails guide and it worked really well.

Right now I'm trying to get some Ids from database and I would use those Ids to get the real objects and do something with them. Getting those is a bit more complex than simple Object.find method.

Here is how my query looks like :

```
select * from quotas q, requests r
where q.id=r.quota_id
and q.status=3
and r.text is not null
and q.id in
(
select A.id from (
select max(id) as id, name 
from quotas
group by name) A
)
order by q.created_at desc
limit 1000;
```

This would give me 1000 ids when executing this query from sql manager. And I was thinking to obtain the list of ids first and then find objects by id.

Is there a way to get these objects directly by using this query? Avoiding ids lookup? I googled that you can execute query like this :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Quota has_many :requests`,

```
Quota.includes(:requests).
  where(status:3).
  where('requests.text is not null').
  where("quotas.id in (#{subquery_string_here})").
  order('quotas.created_at desc').limit(1000)
```

I'm by no means an expert but most basic SQL functionality is baked into ActiveRecord.  You might also want to look at the `#group` and `#pluck` methods for ways to eliminate the ugly string subquery.

Calling `#to_sql` on a relationship object will show you the SQL command it is equivalent to, and may help with your debugging.

Comment: thanks for your response I'm getting this error `missing FROM-clause entry for table "quotas"`. Where am I missing the from, can you tell

Answer (score 0):

I would use find_by_sql for this. I wouldn't swear that this is exactly right, but as I recall you can pretty much plonk an SQL statement into a find_by_sql and the resulting columns will be returned as attributes of an array of objects of the class you call it on:

```
  status = 3
  Quota.find_by_sql('
    select * 
    from quotas q, requests r
    where q.id=r.quota_id
    and q.status= ?
    and r.text is not null
    and q.id in
    (
      select A.id from (
      select max(id) as id, name 
      from quotas
      group by name) A
    )
    order by q.created_at desc
    limit 1000;', status)
```

If you come to Rails as someone used to writing raw SQL, you're probably better off using this syntax than stringing together a bunch of ActiveRecord methods - the result is the same, so it's just a matter of what you find more readable.

Btw, you shouldn't use string interpolation (i.e. #{variable} syntax) inside an SQL query. Use the '?' syntax instead (see my example) to avoid SQL injection potential.